# Create a REST API from a Web Service Operation with IBM API Connect

Tags: rest, soap, ibm-api-management, apiconnect

I would like to create a REST API from a Web Service Operation with IBM API Connect.
On IBM API Management 4 we can create a REST API and assemble a Web Service Invoke Operation by wsdl.
We can connect, discover, define, configure and review operation into "Assemble" tab in API Manager console.

How can we do same thing with IBM API Connect? I have tried to create a REST API but I can't find the same functionality.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is still available in API manager in APIConnect 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.apionprem.doc/tutorial_apionprem_expose_SOAP.html

In the latest release there is now the option to do this in the developer environment too https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/create_api_wsdl.html

Comment: @Ant: Did this answer solve your issue. If so can you please mark the question as answered.